# How to open a save as dialog from javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, blob.topdf

I have a pdf file as a blob in javascript. I want to save the it on my local machine. I am creating an anchor tag, and simulating the click event to download the file.

I want to open the "Save as" dialog of the browser, so that the users are able to set the name and location of the file. Is there any way we can invoke the save as dialog from javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, modern web technologies do not allow you to manipulate the end-user's browser experience. Whether or not a "Save As" dialog pops up is a decision set by each user at the browser level.

This isn't something that you will be able to reliably handle in JavaScript. Even if you're willing to build an entirely custom HTML/JavaScript "Save As" UI which allows them to rename the file before they press the download button, you won't be able to dictate WHERE it saves. This is entirely controlled by the browser and each browser has their own setting for how downloads work and where they go.